# can interface builder be used for creating custom class instances

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

i read several articles about interface builder but its not getting clear to me.
All I want to do is create a separate class(viewSwitcher) for switching the views of my app.   A method take two arguments of uiview type and by using transitionfromview it switches app views.
I want to create objects in interface builder not to code by hand and pass it to my viewSwitcher class.
I am trying to take maximum advantage of interface builder less code and put interfce builder on work.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add any custom object into a nib file, just add one of the existing objects from the palette that is your custom object's superclass, for example if you have a custom UIView subclass, add a UIView from the palette into your nib.

Then, in the identity inspector, you can choose your custom subclass. Any outlets and actions you have defined in your subclass will then be available in interface builder to connect as you require.

Comment: thanks for the answer and help i wish i can select both answers as best answer

Answer (score 1):

You can create instances of a custom class in Interface Builder but you still need to write the code for the actual class.

Interface builder isn't a visual coding tool, it's a way of configuring objects, whether they are provided by the system or custom classes written by yourself.

Comment: thanks for the answer and help i wish i can select both answers as best answer..... yes i know IB is not a visual coding tool just want to manage my objects in it and pass it to my custom class for switching views so that if i want to use switch view function in another app i will simply copy paste file in new app create objs in IB and complete my work in few minutes and it applies for all other logics similar to that.